# Use Burnside's theorem to find the colourings of an octahedron

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions

The question is to find in how many ways we can colour the edges of an octahedron with $k$ colours by using Burnside's theorem.

I already know that I'm supposed to find the automorphism group to get $|G|$ (I assume that it contains all the rotations we can do) and then the fixed point set for each rotation. After that, I'm pretty lost.

I assume that we could rotate it with an axis through each face, vertex and edge? When I'm trying to do that though I feel pretty lost. Would really appreciate some tips and help with this. Reading material would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's enumerate the different rotations:

- There's the identity operator. This has 8 fixed sets (each face).
- For each vertex, we can turn it by $90^{\circ}$. That's 6 operations, and each has 2 fixed point sets (the top four faces, the bottom 4 faces).
- For each pair of opposing edges, we can turn it by $180^{\circ}$. There are 6 such pairs of edges. Each has 4 fixed point sets.
- For each face, we can turn it by $120^{\circ}$. That's 8 operations, and each has 4 fixed point sets.
- Finally, for each pair of opposing vertices, we can turn them by $180^{\circ}$. There are 3 such pairs, and each has 4 fixed point sets.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your reply! Why can we only turn each vertex $90^{\circ}$ and each pair of vertices $180^{\circ}$?

Comment: I think generally my problem is that I can't visualize it, like for example I don't really understand why we can turn edges $180^{\circ}$ as well.

Comment: For this kind of thing, having an actual octahedron to play with helps.
As for the other question: each vertex-pair gives us 3 rotations (of $90^{\circ}$, $180^{\circ}$, $270^{\circ}$) but the $180^{\circ}$ gives a different fixed point set. Also, turning 1 vertex $270^{\circ}$ is the same as turning the opposing one $90^{\circ}$. I tried to stick to the description in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma#Example_application as much as possible.

Comment: Each edge has a symmetry: it borders 2 equal faces. So, we can flip it over. Every face gets swapped with another face.

Comment: For the octahedron, it also helps to realize that an octahedron is the dual of a cube (one vertex per face of the cube, one face per vertex of the cube) so the symmetries must correspond as well.